# Oracle how to use distinct command in join

Tags: oracle, join, distinct

Im am trying to get a list of distinct values from one column whilst getting the key column data by inner join on another table as below..table a and table b hold key column of client.
Table b holds column product which has a range of values against a range of client numbers

Table a holds only client numbet

Table b holds client number and product

```
Client       product
1.                A
1.                  B
2.                  B
3.                   C
```

I want to find the list of distinct product values where the client is in table a and table b
Any suggestions welcome

Comment: Please elaborate your question more.

Comment: `Select Distinct B.Client, B.Product From A INNER JOIN B on A.Client=B.Client`  However a MCVE (Minimally Complete Verifiable Example) would be useful.  Show sample data, what you've tried and what the expected result is.  We're likely not understanding the question.

Comment: Is something wrong in: `select distinct product from a join b using (client)`?

Answer (score 0):

> find the list of distinct product values where the client is in table
>   a and table b

As you will notice below "distinct" isn't applied in joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      b.Product
FROM TABLEA a
INNER JOIN TABLEB b ON a.Client = b.Client
;
```

The inner join ensures that client exists in both A and B and then the "select distinct" removes any repetition in the list of products.

```
SELECT
      b.Product
    , COUNT(*) AS countof
FROM TABLEA a
INNER JOIN TABLEB b ON a.Client = b.Client
GROUP BY
      b.Product
;
```

An alternative, which also makes a distinct list of products where clients are in A and B is to use `group by`, with the added bonus that this way you can do some extra stuff like counting how often a product is referenced.

try it at [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8e3828/1)